Rotate bones in edit mode without affecting animation
I'm animating a model that was ripped from a video game right now, but all of the bones on the model have the incorrect rotation. This appears to be a glitch with the model-ripping tool I used.

Rotating all affected bones by -90 along the normal direction places the bones in their correct spots. However, I also have a bunch of animations imported from the game as well that I need to maintain, and rotating the bones like this messes them up. Each action is an individual animation on the action editor, and going in and fixing every bone for every animation by hand would take an incredibly long time.
Is there any way I can fix this? A script-based solution would work, I have some experience with programming but not with Blender specifically, so I wouldn't be able to write it myself.


all of the bones on the model have the incorrect rotation

Are you sure about that? If models were made in a software with a different coordinates system, their initial orientation is different from what Blender expects (typically leading to 90⁰ rotations in one or two axes), and the bones will "look" rotated, but the rig is perfectly functional and doesn't need any kind of fixing.

If the mesh looks good when in rest pose, and deforms as expected when you rotate the bones, and the animations you run on that armature look correct, you shouldn't try to "fix" the bones : there's nothing to fix on the technical side.

It may "look wrong" and unintuitive to work with bones that aren't rotated the way you would expect in Blender. And for that, there are sometimes import options that can help with it. Importers often have options to help with that, from force connecting children to changing bone axes entirely:

It needs testing, and be aware that it might make the imported armature incompatible with already existing animations, but it can make the rig look like this:

Otherwise, there may be ways to create a rig on top of the existing one that looks good in Blender and temporarily controls the original while in Blender.
Depending on the game you ripped it from, or its game engine, there might be guides on import options or tools and addons made by the modding community to do exactly that. So I would advise you to look up the game's or game engine's official and unofficial resources.

Changing the bone order to "Temperance" in the GLTF importer fixed it.
